# Stub a Function with Callback

Tags: javascript, sinon, stubbing

Normally I use this code:

```
  aws_stub.S3 = function(){};
  var fake_aws_listObjects = function(params, func){func("failure", null)};
  var fake_aws_listObjects_stub = sinon.spy(fake_aws_listObjects);
  aws_stub.S3.prototype.listObjects = fake_aws_listObjects_stub;
```

To stub a function like the following one:

```
new AWS.S3().listObjects(that.build_params(), function(err, data) {
  if(err){
    that.make_failure_callback();
  }
  else{
    that.add_keys(data);

    if(data.IsTruncated){
      that.make_request(data.NextMarker);
    }else{
      that.make_success_callback(that.keys);
    }
  }
});
```

**The problem** with this stubbing is that on **each request** it **returns the same**

**Now I wanted to do is different stubbing for each call:**

```
  aws_stub.S3 = function(){};
  var fake_aws_truncated = function(params, func){func(null, {
    Contents: [{Key: "3fb252ba-0724-438c-93b6-8cd0fd972a8e/image/1:::2.jpg"}],
    IsTruncated: true,
    NextMarker: "nextMarker"
    })};
  var fake_aws_listObjects = function(params, func){func(null, {Contents: [{
    Key: "3fb252ba-0724-438c-93b6-8cd0fd972a8e/image/2:::3.jpg"
  }]})};

  var fake_aws_listObjects_stub = sinon.stub();
     fake_aws_listObjects_stub.onCall(0).returns(fake_aws_truncated);
      fake_aws_listObjects_stub.onCall(1).returns(fake_aws_listObjects);

  aws_stub.S3.prototype.listObjects = fake_aws_listObjects_stub;
```

**The problem seems to be** `returns`, it doesn't execute the function!!

I also cannot write it like this:

```
fake_aws_listObjects_stub.onCall(0) = fake_aws_truncated;
```

Because this would be a wrong hand assignment!

What do I have to change? Here are the sinon docs: http://sinonjs.org/docs/

Thanks!!

Comment: this is seriously messy code to try and work with. it often makes sense to simply code into its basic parts, removing any context, before posting. like, what has Amazon S3 to do with this question? nothing. and the question title is misleading, compared to your actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably go about it another way.

If you want to stub `AWS.S3.prototype.listObjects`, I would do that like so:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(AWS.S3.prototype, 'listObjects');
```

To call the callback with various values, use `stub.yields()`:

```
stub.onCall(0).yields(null, {
  Contents    : [{Key: "3fb252ba-0724-438c-93b6-8cd0fd972a8e/image/1:::2.jpg"}],
  IsTruncated : true,
  NextMarker  : "nextMarker"
});

stub.onCall(1).yields(null, {
  Contents : [{Key: "3fb252ba-0724-438c-93b6-8cd0fd972a8e/image/2:::3.jpg"}]
});
```

To test your code, you just call `listObjects` like before:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.listObjects(params, function(err, value) {
  ...`value` is now one of the fixtures you declared above...
});
```

To restore to the original version of the method, use one of these:

```
stub.restore();
// OR:
AWS.S3.prototype.listObjects.restore();
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! Before I had something similar also with `yields` what didn't worked out for me! thanks a lot!